# c++ if statement won't work (wont read memory)

Tags: c++

I made a small Whitelist for my program.
But the problem is that it not working.
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

int main();
{
    //Here is the part where it gets the process and it data so i won't type it here, takes too much space.
    string a;
    uintptr_t p = 0x0178B3A8;
    int value = *reinterpret_cast<int *>(p);
    int ID = 22862235;

    printf("Authorizing...\n");

    if(value == ID)
    {
        printf("Authorized, Access Granted\n");
        Sleep(5000);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ERROR004:Account Not On Whitelist\n");
        printf("Shutdowning...\n");

        BYTE newcode[] = {0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90};
        DWORD address = 0x007C122E;

        WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)address, newcode, sizeof(newcode), NULL);
    }
}
```

When it runs it says "ERROR404:Account Not On Whitelist" 
Any Fix???

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: What is this random pointer you're exercising? That seems totally nuts. Is there any explanation of what you're trying to accomplish here? All I can see is a whole lot of arbitrary pointer mashing and direct memory manipulation, both of which are highly worrying and are a sure-fire way to generate *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: What @tadman said. Why do you expect anything in particular to be found at `0x178B3A8?`

Comment: "c++ if statement won't work (wont read memory)" – if statements don't "read memory".

Comment: @CareyGregory Every player from the game got a id.And my id is the "int ID" and "int Value" got the same ID and that id is found at that address

Comment: Where does "that address" come from? There's a lot you're not telling us here. Are you trying to hack another program you don't have source code for?

Comment: One program's `0x0178B3A8` is not the same as an other program's `0x0178B3A8`. Read up on virtual memory.

Comment: So i got this STATIC ADDRESS from a game and i want for c++ identify if the ID is on that address. Because if im on another account then the ID from that address will change so the authorize will fail and if i log in my main account the authorize will work but i dont know why it won't.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this kind of hack is generally unwelcome in the SO community, and extremely unlikely to produce any constructive content.

Comment: @RobloxPlayer You seem oblivious to the fact that one process cannot access the memory of another process through a simple pointer. Each process is isolated, they have their own memory map, and access from one process to another, where necessary, **must** be done through OS-level API calls. The days of system memory being a contiguous, unified chunk of addressable memory, such as is the case in the Commodore 64 days where `PEEK` and `POKE` ruled, are long, long gone.

Answer (score 4):

OP seems to have run afoul of not understanding [Virtual Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

Each process has its own virtual addressing with its unique addressing space where any address may or may not be used. This allows physical storage to be in any physically addressable medium: cache, RAM, disk cache or something esoteric like the spin of paired subatomic particles. As a result all processes may concurrently use the same addresses because every address in every process is mapped to different locations in physical storage.

OP has stated that at 0x0178B3A8 in some unknown process X is a valid ID number.

The OP's program is not process X. Let's call it's execution process Y. In process X 0x0178B3A8 very likely is the address of a user ID. I have no way to confirm this. But since 0x0178B3A8 is a virtual reference, not a physical storage reference, process Y cannot read 0x0178B3A8 and expect anything that process Y did not put there. If Y didn't put anything at 0x0178B3A8, the program's behaviour is undefined.

How to solve this problem I want nothing to do with. Odds are good that it will not end well.